# Will DataAdapter.Fill() call the underlying stored procedure multiple times in a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm writing a basic load test to test a stored procedure. Basically I'm trying to eval the performance when the stored procedure is called several times in a row. The results below seem pretty fast so I just wanted to validate that, in the scenario below, `DataAdpater.Fill(ds)` will not only fill the `ds` dataset on each iteration with the results but also make a new/fresh call to the underlying stored procedure each time it's called:

```
private static void LoadTest()
{
    //var concurrentResults = new List<DataSet>();
    var execTimes = new Dictionary<int, decimal>();
    var connString = @"Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=reports;Integrated Security=True";
    var sprocname = "spMySproc";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sprocname, conn))
        {
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@ReportTypeId", 1),
                new SqlParameter("@ReportPeriodId", 2)
            };

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);

            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                var ds = new DataSet();
                var start = DateTime.Now;
                var result = da.Fill(ds);
                var end = DateTime.Now;
                var elapsedTime = (end - start).Milliseconds;
                execTimes.Add((i + 1), elapsedTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you expect other than that?

Comment: If you want to load-test it, at least run on some threads.....not just sequential over and over.           simplest example:                          Parallel.For(0, 1000, j =>
                {
     AnotherMethodToFillADataSet(j);
                }); // Parallel.For            https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx